# Cmake: How to include a .h file in android studio and call methods of header file from android code

Tags: android, c, cmake, android-studio-2.2, android-native-library

I have an Android application in Android Studio.I want to write my encryption logic in native language(c or cpp). For this, I installed Cmake Plugin.
I have got the AES code from [here](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES128-C).

[Directory Structure of project in Android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELaiT.png)

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)



add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
                         aes

                          # Sets the library as a shared library.
                          SHARED

                          src/main/cpp/aes.c )


add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
                         analyze

                          # Sets the library as a shared library.
                          SHARED

                           src/main/cpp/analyze.c )



find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       aes

                   # Links the target library to the log library
                   # included in the NDK.
                   ${log-lib} )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                        analyze

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

This is the class I'm using to refer the included library and use the function defined in it.

analyze.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "aes.h"

#include <jni.h>

void AES128_ECB_encrypt(const uint8_t*,const uint8_t*,uint8_t*);
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_cppandroid_madhu_com_cppandroid_MainActivity_invokeAESFunction(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                       jobject instance) {

    unsigned char myString [] = "This is my string";
    unsigned char mykey[]="this is key";
    //unsigned  char encryp[];

    const uint8_t *input = &myString[0];
    const uint8_t *key =&mykey[0];
    uint8_t *output;

    AES128_ECB_encrypt(input, key, output);
    return output;
}
```

The problem Im facing is, when i call the invokeAESFunction() from my MainActivity, Im getting an error called : "undefined reference to AES128_ECB_encrypt()." Somebody please help me.

Comment: Who (which library) defines the function `AES128_ECB_encrypt`? Check, that you link (with `target_link_libraries`) against this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CMakeLists.txt should look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(SOURCE cpp/native-lib.c  cpp/aes.c)
add_library( native-lib  SHARED ${SOURCE} )
find_library( log-lib log )
target_link_libraries( native-lib ${log-lib} )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you missed `aes` library loading in your activity: `System.loadLibrary("aes")`